# Custom routes overrides with other routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I have to ask for help here cause I don't know anymore how does it happens and what is wrong here.

Here are the routes:

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "View",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{cid}/{pid}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Read", action = "R", id = UrlParameter.Optional, cid = UrlParameter.Optional, pid = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "JsonResult",
            url: "jsonresult/{id}/{cid}/{pid}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Find", action = "Readable", id = UrlParameter.Optional, cid = UrlParameter.Optional, pid = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Read", action = "Index" }
        );
    }
```

There are serveral problems with it right now:

First - the default that is on bottom does not work at all. I actually makes `"View"` route to be a `Default` route for some reason. 
Second - `JsonResult` route gets `404 error` and if I place it at the top instead, it disappears but then `View` route is not working.

I really do not know how to fix ;l

Answer (score 0):

Always place your default route at the top.

Coming to your `jsonresult` issue, You are missing controller name.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Read", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "View",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{cid}/{pid}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Read", action = "R", id = UrlParameter.Optional, cid = UrlParameter.Optional, pid = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "JsonResult",
            url: "{controller}/{id}/{cid}/{pid}", /*Changed to Controller here*/
            defaults: new { controller = "Find", action = "Readable", id = UrlParameter.Optional, cid = UrlParameter.Optional, pid = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );

    }
```